# TypeScript factory return class including type

Tags: typescript

I have a factory function that returns a class (here simplified without the dynamic parts)

```
function factory() {
  class Foo {
  }
  return Foo;
}
```

I can now instanciate the factoried class:

```
const MyFoo = factory();
const foo = new MyFoo();
```

But using it as a type requires me to do:

```
type MyFoo = InstanceType<typeof MyFoo>; //I want to move this line into the factory

let x: MyFoo = new MyFoo();
```

My Question: is there a way to return this type from the factory, so that the user of the factory doesn't have to take care about that?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAhtOAnAngCgJSIDeAUIohADYoDO1iAYnHEaYgL6sYCmUIGSjOAG5iHYhATUoiALJZBiALzI0UTLjwioWAA5dZ8pksQBJMFJSQuAFV1cAPNr1xgBwQD4hiAPTeTiAHdLaTVEAFs4ADd9KAALGDoKGDB9ZNC4-VR0bGJiCh5EAA8ALjcjZRSAsrh8ESA)

Comment: `let x: ReturnType<typeof factory>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.

There is an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#36348](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36348) to automatically bind all named class constructor *values* to a named *type* the constructor value's instance type.  If that were ever implemented, then `const MyFoo = factory();` would let you write `let x: MyFoo = new MyFoo()` without any extra work.  Unfortunately this probably couldn't be implemented without breaking a lot of people (e.g., what happens if there were already a type named `MyFoo` in scope? Would this be an error?  Would the existing type take precedence? etc) and regardless it's not part of the language today.

For now you'll just have to manually define the type.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to return `typeof Foo`. E.g.

```
function factory(): typeof Foo {
    class Foo {
    }
    return Foo;
}
```

Types of `const MyFoo` and `const foo` from your example will be inferrered by the `factory()` return type.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking about, unfortunately.